# How to place nodes around a circle from some initial angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, foreach, tikz-chains

The code below generates 6 nodes placed around a circle at angles 60, 120, 180, ..., 360 with labels 1, 2, 3, ..., 6, respectively.

[image: z6]

However, I would like to place these 6 nodes in the way (where the initial angle for node $0$ is $90$):

[image: z6-from-center-small]

How to draw this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain = z6 placed {at = (\tikzchaincount * 60:1.5)}]
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 6} {
    \node [on chain] {\i};
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? Make it simple ;)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {90,30,...,-210} \node at (\i:1.5) {\j};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90,start chain = z6 placed {at = (\tikzchaincount * 60:1.5)}]
  \foreach \i in {5, ...,0} {
    \node [on chain] {\i};
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]